# Launching a Project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to run my projects in Eclipse, whenever I used to run any program a window appear and it shows that project is launching and building.

This never happened before. In fact, it was working very okay an hour before but now, even for old created project it showing this and not moving ahead.

Is this a general thing happened in eclipse as I haven't seen this before.

I want to get out of this to move ahead and to run the project.

**The Launcher looks like this :**

[image: The progress bar is not moving ahead]

The progress Bar is also not moving ahead if it's building the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I don't know what was the error and why it was displaying the Launcher window and stuck there. But, I forcefully stopped eclipse using Task Manager and then restarted it.

When restarted it took few minutes (more than usual time) and I was done with it. now it's working okay.

Re-installation of Eclipse also worked but i tried this before re-installing or upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely normal to see; there's times I'll see it two or three times in a day. It shows up if the launching process is waiting on anything or is expected to take more than a couple seconds.

In your case, it seems to be stuck on "Building workspace," which happens when you open Eclipse. The more projects you have in Eclipse and the more sections of workspace you have (groups of tabs), the longer it takes to build your workspace. So I'm going to wager a guess that you tried to launch a project within the first minute or two of Eclipse being open. Am I right?

If that's the case, just wait a bit, and watch the lower right corner (where it says "Launching Clock" in your screenshot). When it shows it's stopped trying to do start-up tasks, you should be good to go.

If Eclsipse had been open for a while, then perhaps Eclipse is busy with other junk and calling it "Building workspace." Maybe it's having a hard time understanding what to do with one of your projects, so check for compiler errors. You can also try to "clean" your projects (Project -> Clean).

If that also fails...hmmm...I'm sure there's other options before you get to this point, but you might need to re-install Eclipse. I suppose there's a chance that in the deep dark corners of Eclipse, a file was corrupted, causing Eclipse to hang on a task that requires a missing/bad file. But before you go this far, make you get second or third opinions, because I might be missing some simpler cause of your Eclipse hanging than what I've listed already.

Comment: Launching of Project Clock cancelled by me and Eclipse was opened long back before I tried to run this program. Now, its not even letting me to exit Eclipse :(